# Java Substituting Variables

Tags: java, string, variables, double

If the variables are entered directly (i.e (5.00, 20.00) it calculates the change perfectly, but if I substitute the values with purchase and amount it doesn't calculate the change?

```
public static void makeChange()
   {

       double purchase;
       double tendered;

       Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

       System.out.println ("How much was the Purchase?");
       purchase = scan.nextDouble(); 
       System.out.println ("Amount Tendered"); 
       tendered = scan.nextDouble();


       System.out.println("Processing Transaction");
       int ch[] = cd.makeChange(purchase, tendered); // does not calculate change correctly





           ...continued
```

Comment: Do you get an error or just the wrong result? Can you show us the `makeChange(double, double)` method?

Comment: Just the wrong result, everything turned out to be zero

Comment: Try printing `purchase` and `tendered` and see if they contain the values you think.

Comment: They do, they print exactly what I entered as a user

Comment: looks as Scanner.nextDouble() fails! Have you checked the readen values? Try printing them as @Keppil mentioned! 

-sry came to late ;)

Comment: as a general note, don't use doubles for monetary values.  As for your problem, just use a debugger to see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using arithmetics and comparison using `double`, which will produce unpredictable results as soon as any intermediate value is a number that can't be exactly represented by a `double`. For example, consider this innocent-looking loop:

```
double value = 1.0;
double dime = 0.1;
while (value > 0) {
   value -= dime;
   System.out.println(value);
}
```

This prints:

```
0.9
0.8
0.7000000000000001
0.6000000000000001
0.5000000000000001
0.40000000000000013
0.30000000000000016
0.20000000000000015
0.10000000000000014
1.3877787807814457E-16
-0.09999999999999987
```

Further reading about why that is the case can be found here: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

As was suggested in your previous question, change your `double` variables into `BigDecimal`s and I think your problems will go away.

Comment: Is there a reason BigDecimal doesn't work as an identifier, when double does?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Your program should work with `BigDecimal`s, there is even a `nextBigDecimal()` method for your `Scanner`.

Comment: BigDecimal doesn't highlight like int, char, or double. The reason it was always resulting in zero was because I had to load the change drawer with money(values) first, before trying to take away any change. Thanks anyway, this has been really useful.